# How to get time for which button was not clicked in Android Activity

Tags: android, xml, android-intent, android-activity

I am writing a simple application ,  in which I have to calculate the time for which the button was not clicked in that activity.
Its very important to get the exact time.
Please help me

```
//if(buttonPlayStop.didTouchFocusSelect()){
    buttonPlayStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            buttonPlayStopClick();  //calls this method
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {  //stop button after particular time
                public void run() {
                    v.setClickable(true);
                    thread.start();
                }
            }, 5000); //end

        }

    });
```

Thank You

Comment: add your code to see what you tried

Comment: //if(buttonPlayStop.didTouchFocusSelect()){
        buttonPlayStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                buttonPlayStopClick();  //calls this method
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {  //stop button after particular time
                    public void run() {
                        v.setClickable(true);
                        thread.start();
                    }
                }, 5000); //end
               
            }
            
        });  //i used thread

Comment: man, add it to the question and format it, nobody is going to read that text sausage

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the start date when you want to start counting and then get the date when the user clicks the button, then subtract the two intervals and you will get the exact time.

I'm assuming first click will start the count and second click will end it.

```
buttonPlayStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    boolean started = false;
    long start = 0;

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {

        if(!started)
        {
            start = (new Date()).getTime();
            started = true;
        }
        else
        {
            long end = (new Date()).getTime();
            long ellapsedMilliseconds = end-start; // <--here you have the ellapsed time
            started = false;
        }
    }

});
```